# Where should I mount a disk to store backups?

Tags: mount, freebsd, directory-structure, bacula

I'm new to Unix, and wanted to give it a try. I had an old PC lying around and decided to turn it into a network based backup system to keep the data in the other PCs safe. So I installed FreeBSD on it, and set up [Bacula](http://blog.bacula.org/) on it to handle the backups. So far so good.

I'm configuring the system now, and I noticed that the default configuration stores backups in `/tmp`. The FreeBSD manual says that `/tmp` should be used for files that are not usually preserved across a reboot, which is obviously not the case for backups.

I have a separate disk I want to keep the backups on, and I know how to configure Bacula to write to wherever I want it to write to. My question is, where should I mount the disk?

It seems like maybe `/var` would work. I was thinking of creating a `/var/bacula/` directory and mounting my disk there. Would this be appropriate, or is there some other directory that should be used for long term storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a permanently attached disk for storing backups of other hosts, `/var/bacula` is fine; `hier(7)` says `/var` is for "multi-purpose log, **temporary**, **transient** and spool files" (emphasis mine). Backups by their very nature change over time, making `/var` a good choice. `MySQL`, on some platforms, is configured to use `/var` as its primary storage, for example.

Alternatively, you could mount it at `/usr/local/bacula` to follow the FreeBSD convention of putting software installed from ports, and its associated configuration and data files, under `/usr/local`. On the other hand, I have my backups stored under a new top-level directory, `/data`, which also contains my NFS and SMB shares.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the disk where ever you like. On Linux it's either /mnt or /media.

From https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/dirstructure.html:

```
/mnt/   Empty directory commonly used by system administrators as a temporary mount point.
```

Comment: I understand I can mount my disks anywhere. I'm not asking where can I mount, I'm asking, given the intended use of the disk, where should I. 

From your own quote, /mnt is meant as a temporary mount point, and /media doesn't even exist on FreeBSD. This is an internal hard drive for long term storage, so neither really applies.

Comment: Just like I said, mount it anywhere you like. If you fancy it, create /media and mount it there. It really doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I'm just saying, "mount it anywhere" isn't much of an answer. I know that in technical terms it doesn't matter. The computer doesn't have an opinion, and it will happily read and write to the disk anywhere I mount it. But it does matter from an administrative perspective. If it didn't, there wouldn't be a page dedicated to directory structure. 

I'm trying to learn best practices, not just do "whatever works".